# Table of Contents is using regular (Arabic) numbers for pages whose numbers are Roman

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, table-of-contents, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 Word. Pages that have page numbers displayed as Roman numerals are displayed in the Table of Contents with Arabic numeral page numbers.

Here is a screenshot of the Table of Contents:

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing that the "ABBREVIATIONS" are on page "IV":

[image]

How do I change this to use Roman Numerals?

Comment: If you use sections properly but you still get this problem, you'll need to upload your file, at least the first pages

Answer (score 1):

Word should automatically pick the correct numbering type from the section the heading comes from, just make sure that the numbering format is set per section, so that you insert a section break and then change the numbering type by going to the header/footer -> Page Number -> Format Page Number.

If you changed the numbering of the individual field (through Right Click -> Edit Field) then this will not be reflected in the TOC.

Comment: that is what i did but it is not picking in this case :(

Comment: Can you try the same thing in a blank document and see if it works then?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

I fixed this by entering the footer on the offending page(doublle click on footer), right clicking on the page number, select toggle field codes, ensure that all you see is "{PAGE   * MERGEFORMAT}, if you see something like "* ROMAN" delete it. right click, select update field. your page number may now be in arabic. change the page number back to roman by right clicking on the page number, select "format page number" and changing the number format dropdown to roman numerals.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and could fix it by double clicking the footer, Right-Click on the number field and go to "Format Page Numbers" and set it to roman numbers there.
The numbers were Roman before, dont get me wrong, but by changing this the TOC also recognized that.

Answer (score -1):

My problem solved by updating table page numbers only

[image]

**Hover the table and select update table**